# Implication Operator

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, logic-translation

I think I fail to understand why I might be wrong in the way I translate the following formulas in English.

```
D stand for 'I will eat'

R stand for 'I will drink'
```

1. `¬R -> ¬D`

My answer: I will not eat if I will not drink.

Because of order of precedence and the not operator goes first:

Could be: I will not eat, I will not drink therefore.

2. `¬(D ∧¬R )`

My answer: I will not eat and I will drink.

I think:
The operation in the parenthesis evaluates to false.

Could it be: I will eat and I will not drink. ?

thank you for looking at the problem.

**Update:**

Possible answer for the second question:

I will drink and I will eat.

logic:
evaluation in the () is false

---

**Second update**

As per comment I am still missing out and I should read on De Morgan's laws
not() => true

If i remove the parentheses I would have:

Possible answer:

`I will not eat and I will not drink.`

Comment: You have an error in logic for your second problem.  The logic of your first solution is sound, but some might object to your English phrasing of it. I am okay with how you answered the first part, but a computer checking of it might be thrown off by the flexible workings of the English language.

Comment: For the first question, for a computer to evaluate would be: 'If I will not drink, I will not eat'.

I am afraid I don't see my error.
I evaluate the operation in the parentheses  and then I apply the not operator to the statements.

Comment: ca anyone explain why my question has been marked -1? 
I have provided with example, solution and possible solution.

Comment: I'm not your downvoter, but as a new participant you have not done some of the basic steps to [ask a good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  In particular rather than editing the body of the Question to address what I pointed out about your second part, you have posted an Answer "for the second question".  But what you've written there likely repeats the same mistake.  See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: If no mathematical rules are involved and just pure translation, could it be my latest update?

Comment: My point is that "not (P and Q)" is logically equivalent to "(not P) or (not Q)".  Note that we don't simply "remove parentheses".  The denial of a conjunction is the *disjunction* of two denials.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

- D stand for 'I will eat'
- R stand for 'I will drink' \begin{equation}\tag{1} \lnot R\rightarrow \lnot D \end{equation} \begin{equation}\tag{2} \lnot(D\land\lnot R) \end{equation}

Your first answers are correct, although I had to read your second attempt twice before I understood the meaning. I would personally write $(1)$ as "If I will not drink, then I will not eat".

In general, when it's not that case that two things ($D$ and $\lnot R$) are true, at least one of them is false. This means the English translation of $(2)$ would be "Either I will drink, or I will not eat, or both".